# Sorting search result in Lucene based on a numeric field

Tags: java, lucene

I have some docs with two fields: text, count.

I've used `Lucene` to index docs and now I want to search in text and get the result sorted by count in descending order. How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default search implementation of Apache Lucene returns results sorted by score (the most relevant result first), then by id (the oldest result first).

This behavior can be customized at query time with an additionnal Sort parameter .

TopFieldDocs Searcher#search(Query query, Filter filter, int n, Sort sort)

The Sort parameter specifies the fields or properties used for sorting. The default implementation is defined this way :

```
new Sort(new SortField[] { SortField.FIELD_SCORE, SortField.FIELD_DOC });
```

To change sorting, you just have to replace fields with the ones you want :

```
new Sort(new SortField[] {
SortField.FIELD_SCORE,
new SortField("field_1", SortField.STRING),
new SortField("field_2", SortField.STRING) });
```

This sounds simple, but will not work until the following conditions are met :

- You have to specify the type parameter of SortField(String field, int
  type) to make Lucene find your field, even if this is normaly
  optional.
- The sort fields must be indexed but not tokenized :

  `document.add (new Field ("byNumber", Integer.toString(x), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));`
- The sort fields content must be plain text only. If only one single
  element has a special character or accent in one of the fields used
  for sorting, the whole search will return unsorted results.

Check this [tutorial](http://mygeekjourney.com/index.php/2013/06/05/apache-lucene-how-to-sort-results-by-alphabetical-order/).

Comment: @HomayounAfshari You're welcome, and sorry i didn't get your question, what do you mean exactly by : `sort order`

Comment: I use this method and result now is sorted but in Ascending order and i cant change this.

Comment: The field type is in a subclass `SortField.Type`, so for String it's `SortField.Type.STRING`

Answer (score 4):

Below line will do the trick. Last parameter is `boolean reverse` if you set it to true it will sort in reverse order i.e. descending in your case.

```
  SortField longSort = new SortedNumericSortField(FIELD_NAME_LONG, SortField.Type.LONG, true);
```

Sample code:

```
  IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
  Query q = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[] { FIELD_NAME_NAME}, analyzer).parse("YOUR_QUERY") );

  SortField longSort = new SortedNumericSortField(FIELD_NAME_LONG, SortField.Type.LONG, true);

  Sort sort = new Sort(longSort);
  ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.search(q, 10 , sort).scoreDocs;
```

Also it's necessary that you add you sort enabled field as a `NumericDocValuesField` when you create your index.

```
 doc.add(new NumericDocValuesField(FIELD_NAME_LONG, longValue));//sort enabled field
```

Code is as per lucene-core-5.0.0

Answer (score 1):

first:

```
Fieldable count = new NumericField("count", Store.YES, true);
```

second:

```
SortField field = new SortField("count", SortField.INT);
Sort sort = new Sort(field);
```

third:

```
TopFieldDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 20, sort);
ScoreDoc[] sds = docs.scoreDocs;
```

Like this is OK !