# Weightened City Index

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I created a index of cities with the following properties

1. Name
2. Population
3. Country

With the following code I can run searches and got results

```
var parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Name", analyzer);

Query query = parser.Parse(searchTerm);

TopScoreDocCollector result = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(resultCount, true);
searcher.Search(query, result);
```

For example, when I run `Berlen~` as a fuzzy query I got some results. But the city Berlin -with highest Population- is some where in the middle. How can I influence the query to have cities with higher population value to get a higher score?

Answer (score 1):

The default order of results is by relevance (score). What you should do is not manipulating score to change the order but it is sorting results by Population field.

Check [Sorting search result in Lucene based on a numeric field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21965849/1327005)